# What is the best way to make a specific CSS code work in IE6 to the newest version of IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, ckeditor

I am looking for the best way to make this CSS work in IE6 to the newest version.

```
body:first-child *
{
    margin-top:0 !important;
}

body:last-child *
{
    margin-bottom:0 !important;
}
```

So what would be to do it?

This CSS is loaded inside of the CKEDITOR.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the context but I'm not sure that's the best way to do it. `*` should be used carefully and if you're adding `!important` then something must be wrong...
Why don't you give those elements a class and style that instead to avoid headaches with IE6?

Comment: I am using !important for "testing" reasons.

Comment: The only problem I have run into is when I do body:first-child * it does not work... Only body:last-child * works.

Comment: That's weird because IE6 doesn't support any of those two pseudo selectors, and IE7 and IE8 don't support `last-child`. You can use [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) it might help...That's why I'm saying, there must be a better way to do it.